# Variable Frame Rate in iPhone video

Tags: iphone, camera, avfoundation

How can we change frame rates of an existing video as well as while capturing video from iPhone?

Can we implement it using either AVFoundation framework or by any third party library?

Answer (score 0):

Code for choosing custom frame rate is as below - Added checks to [Apple RosyWriter](https://github.com/hpp/Penny/blob/473239bf4904a570531c3be66b592556ea331517/Penny/RosyWriterCapturePipeline.m#L344) to verify if current format supports FPS chosen

```
- (void)configureCamera:(AVCaptureDevice *)videoDevice withFrameRate:(int)desiredFrameRate
{
    BOOL isFPSSupported = NO;
    AVCaptureDeviceFormat *currentFormat = [videoDevice activeFormat];
    for ( AVFrameRateRange *range in currentFormat.videoSupportedFrameRateRanges ) {
        if ( range.maxFrameRate >= desiredFrameRate && range.minFrameRate <= desiredFrameRate )        {
            isFPSSupported = YES;
            break;
        }
    }

    if( isFPSSupported ) {
        if ( [videoDevice lockForConfiguration:NULL] ) {
            videoDevice.activeVideoMaxFrameDuration = CMTimeMake( 1, desiredFrameRate );
            videoDevice.activeVideoMinFrameDuration = CMTimeMake( 1, desiredFrameRate );
            [videoDevice unlockForConfiguration];
        }
    }
}
```

*In case current format (`activeFormat`) didn't support your chosen FPS,  use below code to change `activeFormat` and then chose FPS. Will need to get format dimension to match your needs though.*

```
- (void)configureCamera:(AVCaptureDevice *)device withFrameRate:(int)desiredFrameRate
{
    AVCaptureDeviceFormat *desiredFormat = nil;
    for ( AVCaptureDeviceFormat *format in [device formats] ) {
        for ( AVFrameRateRange *range in format.videoSupportedFrameRateRanges ) {
            if ( range.maxFrameRate >= desiredFrameRate && range.minFrameRate <= desiredFrameRate ) {
                desiredFormat = format;
                goto desiredFormatFound;
            }
        }
    }

    desiredFormatFound:
    if ( desiredFormat ) {
        if ( [device lockForConfiguration:NULL] == YES ) {
            device.activeFormat = desiredFormat ;
            device.activeVideoMinFrameDuration = CMTimeMake ( 1, desiredFrameRate );
            device.activeVideoMaxFrameDuration = CMTimeMake ( 1, desiredFrameRate );
            [device unlockForConfiguration];
        }
    }
}
```

Note: Usage of `AVCaptureConnection` `videoMinFrameDuration` to set FPS is deprecated.